# Mongo Nested queries

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, object

I need to query based on key's that all equal the same thing, let's say the following is an order, and that order contains three products. I need to query orders, that have products, that have a specific status all equal to true. Each product is stored, with a mongo id as its key, so I don't actually know it's key name, Example: (obviously I've shortened the keys)

```
{
  "_id" : "foo",
  "products": {
    "123": {
      "status": {
        "a": false,
        "b": true,
        "c": true,
      },
    },
    "213": {
      "status": {
        "a": true,
        "b": true,
        "c": true,
      },
    },
    "321": {
      "status": {
        "a": false,
        "b": false,
        "c": true,
      },
    }
  },
}
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
$this->database->$collection->find(
    array('_id' => 'foo', 'products.$.status.c' => true)
);
```

I'd expect the above, to return the complete order in the example, as the status 'c' inside each product is true, if I were to perform the same query, but with 'a' or 'b' as the status query, it wouldn't return it.

I'm not really sure how to do this, obviously the above didn't work, so my question is, how can I match on multiple sub keys of an array of objects that I do not know the key name?

Answer (score 0):

You want an array of documents, not an object with the id as its key. The $ positional operator doesn't work on objects.

```
{
  "_id" : "foo",
  "products": [
    {
      id: "123"
      "status": {
        "a": false,
        "b": true,
        "c": true,
      },
    },
    {
      id: "213"
      "status": {
        "a": true,
        "b": true,
        "c": true,
      },
    },
    {
      id: "321"
      "status": {
        "a": false,
        "b": false,
        "c": true,
      },
    }
  ]
}
```

Your query needs to look like this:

```
$this->database->$collection->find(
    array('_id' => 'foo', 'products.status.c' => true)
);
```

This returns the cursor at the first 'product' that matches your query
and on udpate.

```
$this->database->$collection->find(
    array('_id' => 'foo', 'products.status.c' => true),
    array('products.$.hello' => 'world')
);
```

This updates only that sub document. The only time you should use objects is if you know what the keys will be. Like status, or address... but if key is a variable as well, it gets really tricky, really quickly.

Comment: I don't have control over the way it's stored so this doesn't really help me unfortunately, I can't change the format

Comment: If you don't have control over it, there's no way to do this then. :( Other than retrieving ALL documents and sorting that way.

Comment: Not even with a map-reduce?

Comment: You would still need to know the keys.

Comment: I could be wrong though. this is just my experience. I wish you the best of luck. :)